# Syzygy, inexorable, pancreatic, phantasmagoria

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could you please explain to me what this statement means? And why is it funny?

> Syzygy, inexorable, pancreatic, phantasmagoria — anyone who can use
>   those four words in one sentence will never have to do manual labor.
>   — W.P. Kinsella

Comment: That doesn't seem a particularly difficult challenge. Like, "Alice watched the night sky in awe as the moon approached syzygy, and reflected that her impending inexorable death from pancreatic cancer was just one small part in the phantasmagoria that is the universe." But then, I've never had to do manual labor.

Comment: @Jay W.P. Kinsella did it much more easily.

Comment: @Jay: *"Syzygy, inexorable, pancreatic, and phantasmagoria are uncommon words"*. Those of us who *have* done manual labour know the value of not expending unnecessary effort. Why write a 34-word sentence just to prove you might actually know the *meanings*, as well as be able to write them all in a sentence? Anyway, the question itself seems Too Localised to me.

Comment: Requests to explain a joke are off topic at this site. Please see the [faq].

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, there's no challenge at all if you just refer to them as words. Why did you even need the word "uncommon"?

Comment: @Jay: I just liked the symmetry of having four common words and four uncommon ones in my sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are four obscure and unrelated words and would be difficult to work into a single sentence (I had to look up [syzygy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/syzygy)). The implication is that if you can work them into a single sentence, you're sufficiently educated or intellectually inclined that you will be able to find a "desk job" as opposed to having to do manual labour.

Answer (score 3):

I think it means you have to be extremely well-educated to use those four words in one sentence, so you will have no problem finding good job that doesn't require manual labor)

Comment: It's very easy to use _syzygy_, _inexorable_, _pancreatic_, and _phantasmagoria_ in a single sentence. If one allows word-as-a-word usages.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - what is that, pray tell?

Comment: @JAM As Kinsella did.